# Is their any way to connect vocareum (aws student portal) with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, connectivity, amazon-transcribe

I have tried to do with boto3 but boto3 redirected to the main portal of AWS not on vocareum.
first it give me error that couldn't connect to the server and now it is

ClientError:
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Comment: What code are you actually using?

Comment: From this 

import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)

to this 

import boto3
import time
import urllib
import json

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your_aws_access_key_id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your_aws_secret_access_key'

job_name = 'job name'
job_uri = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file_name.mp3'

transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region_name='us-east-1')

transcribe.start_transcription_job(.etc)
Nothing is working
@JammyDodger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, but since the credentials issued by Vocareum (AWS Educate) are temporary credentials, you also need to pass the `aws_session_token` to boto3 -

```
import boto3
import time
import urllib
import json

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your_aws_access_key_id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your_aws_secret_access_key'
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = 'your_aws_session_token'

job_name = 'job name'

job_uri = 's3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file_name.mp3'

transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe',
                          aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                          aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                          aws_session_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
                          region_name='us-east-1')
```

Also, you need to keep track of the session timer on your Vocareum dashboard as the token will expire when your session expires.  You can refresh the timer by refreshing the Vocareum page.